# What is the most efficient way to "flatten" a JSON within a dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I'm having trouble loading a big JSON lines file in pandas, mainly because I need to "flatten" one of the resulting columns after using pd.read_json
For example, for this JSON line:

```
{"user_history": [{"event_info": 248595, "event_timestamp": "2019-10-01T12:46:03.145-0400", "event_type": "view"}, {"event_info": 248595, "event_timestamp": "2019-10-01T13:21:50.697-0400", "event_type": "view"}], "item_bought": 1909110}
```

I'd need to load 2 rows with 4 columns in pandas like this:

```
+--------------+--------------------------------+--------------+---------------+
| "event_info" |       "event_timestamp"        | "event_type" | "item_bought" |
+--------------+--------------------------------+--------------+---------------+
|       248595 | "2019-10-01T12:46:03.145-0400" | "view"       |       1909110 |
|       248595 | "2019-10-01T13:21:50.697-0400" | "view"       |       1909110 |
+--------------+--------------------------------+--------------+---------------+
```

The thing is, given the size of the file (413000+ lines, over 1GB), none of the ways that I managed to do it is fast enough for me. I was trying a rather rudimentary way, iterating over the loaded dataframe, creating a dictionary and appending the values to an empty dataframe:

```
history_df = pd.read_json('data/train_dataset.jl', lines=True)
history_df['index1'] = history_df.index
normalized_history = pd.DataFrame()
for index, row in history_df.iterrows():
    for dic in row['user_history']:
        dic['index1'] = row['index1']
        dic['item_bought'] = row['item_bought']
        normalized_history = normalized_history.append(dic, ignore_index=True)
```

So the question is which would be the fastest way to accomplish this? Is there any way without iterating the whole history_df dataframe?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you please provide the way you tried that didn't quite work? Also, what size of files are we talking here?

Comment: If you can include the code you have so far, that would be helpful in review and debugging. Also, when you indicate 'fastest way', that is largely dependent on the environment you are running the code.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak Sorry for missing that, edited the question with the info

Comment: @etch_45 Added the code, thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe if you try this?:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

data = []

# assuming each line from data/train_dataset.jl 
# is a json object like the one you posted above:

with open('data/train_dataset.jl') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(json.loads(line))

normalized_history = pd.json_normalize(data, 'user_history', 'item_bought')
```